# NoMethodError - undefined method `status' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to work through my table and pull out and list each of the status types under their own heading. When I run this I get NoMethodError for Tickets#index with the error reading undefined method `status' for nil:NilClass

index.html.erb

```
<h2>New<h2>
<% if @ticket.status == 'New' %>
    <% tickets.each do |ticket| %>
                    <p><%= link_to ticket_path(ticket) do %>
                        <strong><%= ticket.category %></strong>
                    <% end %></p>
                    <p><%= ticket.requestor_name %></p>
                    <p><%= ticket.requestor_lab %></p>
                    <p><%= ticket.contact %></p>
                    <p><%= ticket.requested_by %></p>
                    <%= ticket.status %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The code basically repeats for the other status types.

Controller:

```
 def index
    @tickets = Ticket.all

    if params[:filter_by]
        @tickets = Ticket.where(:category => params[:filter_by])
    else
        @tickets = Ticket.all
    end
end
```

Comment: which part of the "if" statement from the controller is running when you get this, are there `params["filter_by]` or not?

Comment: Currently the second part, I have not made it to the filter break outs yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove @ticket condition. As we don't see any definition for the same and use

```
<% if @tickets.any? %>
  <% @tickets.each do |ticket| %>
    <% if ticket.status.downcase == 'new' %>
      <p><%= link_to ticket_path(ticket) do %>
        <strong><%= ticket.category %></strong>
      <% end %></p>
      <p><%= ticket.requestor_name %></p>
      <p><%= ticket.requestor_lab %></p>
      <p><%= ticket.contact %></p>
      <p><%= ticket.requested_by %></p>
      <%= ticket.status %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Except that I only want to list the New tickets, not all of the tickets. What you are suggesting, I already have working. I am wanting to break out the New tickets so that they can be more visible.

Comment: then you need to add condition in loop, let me modify.

Comment: I will attempt this, but there will always be tickets, do I need the first if statement?

Comment: Ideally if you have no records then you can show No records available in else part of first if statement.Or u\you can remove it, if there will not be such case for your application.

Comment: Oh! Great point! That works, although my headers are all bunched at the top, but that is not the point of this question! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

What is causing the error is that there are no `@tickets` being returned.

This line is causing the error

```
<% if @ticket.status == 'New' %>
```

`undefined method ... for nil:NilClass` means that the method is being called on a nil value, so `@tickets` is nil at the moment.

You can test this by adding a check for a value around the `if` statement.

```
<h2>New<h2>
 <% if @tickets.any? %><!-- check for tickets first -->
  <% if @ticket.status == 'New' %>
    <% tickets.each do |ticket| %>
     <p><%= link_to ticket_path(ticket) do %>
       <strong><%= ticket.category %></strong>
     <% end %></p>
                <p><%= ticket.requestor_name %></p>
                <p><%= ticket.requestor_lab %></p>
                <p><%= ticket.contact %></p>
                <p><%= ticket.requested_by %></p>
                <%= ticket.status %>
  <% end %>
 <% end %><!-- remember to add another end -->
<% end %>
```

That should eliminate the error, but it does not fix the `@ticket` variable being empty.

Comment: Ok! Thank you for helping to understand the error and why that first statement needs to be there!